# Swift. Viewcontroller aware of Subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, casting

I have a subclass for a tableview cell.

```
class profileTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableviewUsernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableviewMessageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableviewTimeStamp: UILabel!
}
```

And I need to access these labels in my viewcontroller. How can I go about doing this. I am reasonably new to programming.

-I am getting "unresolved Identifier" obvously on the labels below. How can I access these labels?

-Also tried putting cell.tableViewUsername.text (cell.) infront of all labels still doesnt work.

```
class UserProfile: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = profileTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profileCell")


        //Set username label to display username
        let usernameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        tableviewUsernameLabel.text = profileDataArray[indexPath.row].username


        //Set message label to display message
        let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        tableviewMessageLabel.text = profileDataArray[indexPath.row].message
        tableviewMessageLabel.numberOfLines = 0



        //Set timeStampLabel to current time AGO
        let timeStampLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
        tableviewTimeStamp.text = profileDataArray[indexPath.row].timeStamp
        tableviewTimeStamp.numberOfLines = 0



        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return profileDataArray.count // your number of cell here
    }


}
```

Comment: You deserve some extra credits for coming up with `viewWithTag` to solve your issue ;-) But the answer below provides the standard idiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must [type cast](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) the cell returned by `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` to `profileTableViewCell`.

```
let cell = profileTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profileCell") as! profileTableViewCell

cell.tableviewUsernameLabel.text = ...
cell.tableviewMessageLabel.text = ...
cell.tableviewTimeStamp.text = ...

return cell
```

Comment: BTW, you should really name your class `ProfileTableViewCell`, following the standard Swift naming convention.

Comment: Your the best! Thank you. ;)